# mod_rewrite should I define a url prefix for assets?

Tags: web-framework, apache, rewrite, routing, url

I am working on a little framework where I have this directory tree:

```
project/
|--- ... (directories unrelated to the question)
|--- public/
|     |--- index.php
.htaccess
```

The **.htaccess** sends every request to `project/public/index.php` but I have to add specific rules for assets *(stylesheets, js, images, ...)*.

Searching a lot I started adding a `RewriteCond` for specific extensions as I saw almost everywhere, and `RewriteRule` to catch parts of the URL starting with folder names like `css/` etc:

```
# Send front-end assets in the public directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(bmp|css|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|tiff)$
RewriteRule ((css|js|img)\/.*\..*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But this means I would define which extensions are allowed. And this would also mean I would define a specific list of subdirectories allowed in `public/`.

I'm not an expert with **mod_rewrite**, but I just thought I could define an *"assets prefix"* which, if present in URL, would rewrite the rest of the URL to the `public` directory.
**Example URL:**

```
                   | detect | rewrite to /public/$1
some_route_to_strip/_prefix_/any_custom_dir/any_file.ext
```

- Should I avoid doing that ? If so, why ?
- If not, is the way to handle requests to asset files I almost always encountered a good way to do ?

Comment: Why...........?

Comment: @user253751 using an arbitrary string to detect when an URI is looking for assets could be easier and more reliable than filtering by file extension.

Comment: But why not just use the *actual* path? Instead of telling the browser to fetch `/a/b/c/foo.css` and then rewriting it to `/public/foo.css` why not tell the browser to fetch `/public/foo.css`?

Comment: @user253751 The idea was to link assets with `/_front/foo.css` which would rewrite to `/public/foo.css` to avoid rewriting to the Front Controller like `/public/index.php?_url=/public/foo.css`. But I think I was wrong about my **.htaccess** configuration at the time I wrote that, this can be served directly, only the application should write the correct path to the assets.